# How to include a random array with 2 variable

Tags: php, arrays, random

My `config.php` contains:

```
$a1="title";
$b1="text";
$a2="title2";
$b2="text2";
```

and I have `1.php` which includes `config.php`.

I need to include ($a1 and $b1) or ($a and $b) randomly.

How can I do this? :)

Thank you.

Comment: Its really hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do... Could you please try and explain?

Comment: use two arrays. Store the possible values as array elements in the arrays `$a` and `$b`. Then pick a random index `$i` and use it as `$a[$i]` and `$b[$i]`

Answer (score 1):

If this data is related, and you need a random set, store it in an array:

```
$sets = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'text'  => 'Some text here about the title'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Some other title',
        'text'  => 'Some other text here about the title'
    )
);
```

With this array, we have two indexes that we can choose from:

```
$sets[0]; // Title: Some title, Text: Some text here about the title
$sets[1]; // Title: Some other title, Text: Some other text here about the title
```

If we want one of those, randomly, we could do the following:

```
$index = array_rand( $sets, 1 );
```

This will select either `0`, or `1`. With more entries in our array, the potential for this number to be larger also increases. We can then use it to grab one of our sets of data:

```
$dataSet = $sets[ $index ];
```

And then display the output:

```
echo $dataSet['title'];
echo $dataSet['text'];
```